# Change Query String without full postback

Tags: jquery, postback, query-string

How can I change querystring values without full postback using jquery?

Comment: what do you want to achive with changing the querystring params?

Comment: couldn't understand your issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history)

```
history.pushState(data, title [, url])
```

So you can do

```
history.pushState({}, document.title, "?querystring=1")
```

But since it is not supported by old browsers you can make a fallback function which modifies the hash

```
window.location.href = "#querystring=1";
```

Comment: You can see it working here http://www.orkutmanager.net/ For IE9 it changes the hash, for browsers it changes the URL without posting

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify the URL with JavaScript unless...

- You want to modify the fragment identifier only.
- If you want to use the HTML5 history API. It is not widely supported.

Comment: Not fully Url I actualy want to change querystring parameter like

Comment: @Onur The query string is part of the URL.